# The best way for async/await call funtion?

Tags: javascript, async-await

i wanna know if is good or not remove some await from second or third call.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        let response = await this.CollectionManager.GetAllCollections();
        if(!response.error) {
            this.setState({collections: response.data});
        }
    } catch (e) {
        this.notify("Error can't connect with the server.");
    }
}

async GetAllCollections() {
    try {
        return await this.httpClient.Get(this.api_url);
    }  catch (e) {

    }
}

async Get (url) {
   try {
       return this.Response(await Axios.get(this._apiUrl + url));
   } catch (e) {

   }
}
```

I cannont find more example on internet.

Comment: That depends wether the code needs to wait. Does this "feel" right for your situation?

Comment: So if I remove await for instruction two or three it will return the same? never fail?

Comment: no, it will fail.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need remove await from `componentDidMount`

and read this article maybe can help you https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: wether a method is async or not doesnt matter.